Issue with Hover Effect: Text Inside Box Darkens on Hover Despite Bright Text Color
Here's the properly formatted content for Stack Overflow:

Issue with Hover Effect: Text Inside Box Darkens on Hover Despite Bright Text Color
I'm working on a React component where I have a box that gets darker on hover (due to opacity changes), but I want the text inside the box to remain fully bright regardless of the hover effect. Here's my current code:
Component.jsx:
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './BigBoxContainer.css';

export default function BigBoxContainer(props) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleClick = () => {
        navigate('/');
    };

    return (
        <button className='big-tarot-box' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.img})`}} onClick={handleClick}>
            <div className='box-body'>
                <h3>{props.title}</h3>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className='text-overlay'>
                {props.overlayText}
            </div>
        </button>
    );
}

Component.css:
.big-tarot-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: filter 0.8s ease, opacity 0.8s ease;
}

.big-tarot-box:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: brightness(0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.big-tarot-box:hover .text-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.big-tarot-box {
  position: relative;
}

.big-tarot-box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: opacity 0.8s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.big-tarot-box:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

Expected Behavior:
I want the text inside the box to remain fully bright when the box is hovered over, even when the box gets darker due to the opacity changes.
Current Behavior:
The text inside the box also gets darker when the box is hovered over, which is not the desired behavior.
Attempts:
I've tried adjusting the text color on hover, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired behavior?

You can now copy and paste this formatted content into a new post on Stack Overflow.

As you are applying filter and opacity on hover, the text, which is inside the .big-tarot-box, will also be affected.
I recommend an alternative approach, for example, you could alter the background color of your box instead of altering the properties described above.
I suggest this approach:

Convert your background color to HSL format or RGBA format. For example, #fff equals hsl(0 0% 100%); and rgba(255, 255, 255, 1).
On hover, change the background color opacity directly by modifying the last value on the function. For example, the equivalent for opacity: 0.7; would be hsl(0 0% 70%) or rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)

Lastly, this WILL affect how your text looks because the background affects the contrast, that is inevitable. But it won't alter the opacity or brightness of your text overlay.

Component.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./BigBoxContainer.css";

export default function BigBoxContainer(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        className="big-tarot-box"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${props.img})`,
          opacity: isHovered ? 0.7 : null,
          filter: isHovered ? "brightness(0.2)" : null,
          cursor: isHovered ? "pointer" : null,
        }}
        onClick={handleClick}
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      >
        <div className="box-body">
          <h3>{props.title}</h3>
          <p>{props.description}</p>
        </div>
      </button>
      <div
        className="text-overlay"
        onClick={handleClick}
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
        style={{
          color: isHovered ? "white" : null,
          opacity: isHovered ? 100 : null,
          cursor: isHovered ? "pointer" : null,
        }}
      >
        {props.overlayText}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

Component.css
.big-tarot-box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transition: filter 0.8s ease, opacity 0.8s ease;
  }
  
   .text-overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  
  .big-tarot-box {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .big-tarot-box::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

Here the problem was your text-overlay div was inside the button big-tarot-box So, the CSS of the parent element applies to the child element as well.
I seperated both and change css of both if isHovered state is true else null.
